# Is it possible to be register in two EU countries for health insurance?

Tags: germany, health-insurance, belgium

I'm registered in Germany and it's an obligation to have health insurance (which is very expensive 200€ a month for the basics)
I was previously registered in Belgium and I wonder if I can register myself in Belgium and pay the insurance again and apply for German government to accept this as a valid health insurance to be in Berlin, at least for a year until.

Somebody with any experience on this?

Comment: Will your Belgian insurance actually cover medical costs in Germany? Sidenote: I'm at 500€/month for "voluntary insurance"; covers a family of 4 though. 200€ is not bad for German standards.

Comment: The idea is that Germany accepts my Belgium insurance and I don't need to get another one.

Comment: I think the critical point there is whether you are insured, meaning whether your Belgian insurance covers costs while you're in Germany. If it doesn't do that, Germany *probably* won't accept it as substitute.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through that in the other way, while leaving Germany. Under new regulations in EU, you are obliged to have health insurance in any EU country, which means you are not allowed to unregister until you prove you've got another health insurance.

On the other way, you are not allowed to voluntarily register when you have health insurance in other country (in my case, it meant, I was stuck with expensive German health insurance until I find job in Poland, which I solved by registering a company and getting cheap insurance from it).

It means, if you're from EU, and you don't work or run a company in Germany, you're insured with your old insurance. If you get a job, things got more tricky. In Poland you would be automatically insured by your employer, but German law gives you the option: either you'll be insured by your employer, or you get insured private, in which case you should ask, if it need to be German insurance.

But you must take into account, health insurance in other EU countries is meant to work in emergency cases, not on regular basis. Each case can be checked, if it was necessary for you to use health service abroad, or you could as well go back to your country. You can find it difficult to get sick leave. You won't have German electronic insurance card, which is your password to quick access to your doctor.